# Separating Designers from Main Assembly

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, updates

**Background**

I am converting the TreeViewAdv(TVA) project on SourceForge to vb.net.  Thus far I have successfully converted the code, successfully built it, added a reference of the dll to a new project, added the control to the toolbox, added the control to a form, and modified the controls properties.  I have also coded functionality into the form prior to building that accepted the Aga.Controls namespace.

**The Problem**

When I go to debug the application that I have placed the TVA control in, I get the error: '*'Aga' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.*'  on all calls to that namespace.  So, I researched this problem on SourceForge and there is a thread here: https://sourceforge.net/p/treeviewadv/discussion/568369/thread/005e61ef/ that discusses this issue. Supposedly somebody figured out what the problem is when you are seeing behavior like this, but failed to share any details of their wisdom.  The general issue is that when referencing a dll compiled in 2008 in a 2010 project *'is that VS 2010 requires you have Designers separate from the main assembly.'*  I tried contacting people there, but there seem to be no real activity on any thread in the forum at all.  That leads me to my first question...

**The Question(s)**

1.)  Hoping beyond hope, is there anybody on StackOverflow that has successfully done this for the treeviewadv project specifically?  If so, I would really appreciate either a somewhat detailed description of what was done, or a short description with the final resulting code/fix.  While I understand this is highly unlikely, I thought I would ask before asking more general questions on 'how to'?

2.)  Barring anybody that fits the bill for number 1, is there anybody that has knowledge of this general process and at least enough knowledge of the TVA project and desire to work with me on this endeavor?

2.)  Barring 1 and 2, is there anybody that has done this with any project and can either describe the general process in relative detail, and/or point to example code?

3.)  Barring 1, 2 and 3, is there a particularly good resource that I can access that outlines how to update a VS2008 project in the manner described above?

**Disclaimer**

I understand that this process might be too involved to discuss here, so am willing to take the discussion/effort elsewhere if needed.  If someone of category 1 or 2 can (answer my question/work with me on this) and you feel the discussion should be taken elsewhere please inform me as to how we can contact each other as there seems to be no formal mechanism on S.O..  I am still interested in posting (or linking) the results here for all to share if an answer can be found.

Comment: by `designers` do you mean UI Designers or the standard VS designers? (the latter seems odd, but does the project even have UI designers?)

Comment: I feel your pain.  There is nothing worse than googling an issue, and finding a forum thread written in 2008 with the last post being "It's ok I fixed it!".  WHAT DID YOU DO!!!  WHAT IS THE SORCERY??!!

Comment: @Plutonix - To start, I'm not 100% certain what the user in the sourceforge thread was referring to.  Thus my question here.  The original VS2008 solution had 3 projects in it:

Comment: 1.) Tree - This is the actual control.  It has no files that displays directly as UI when opened (I'll assume that is what you mean by UI Designers).  It does have a file with an associated Designer file (TreeViewAdv.Designer.cs, and I'll assume that is what you meant by VS designer).  
  
2.) a UnitTest Project - Was not necessary to build so I did not import this into my project... so this is not the problem.  
  
3.) a SampleApp Project - Was not necessary to build so I did not import this into my project... so this is not the problem.
  
4.) Don't google VS designer at work.

Comment: A UI designer is the special thing that comes up for some controls to set properties.  DataGridView, ListView, ContextMenuStrip all have extensive UI Designers.  CheckedLstBox and ListBox have UI Designers for editing the initial contents.  Going simply by the name, they may very well be talking about a UI Designer.  If so, the main control/component Class will have an attribute decoration like: `<Designer(GetType(xxxDesigner(Of xxxx)))>`, and another class matching `xxxDesigner`.  Sounds like you "just" need to move it to its own assembly.

Comment: @Plutonix - There may be a problem with moving the designer to its own assembly.  From the MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb514141%28v=vs.100%29.aspx): *'You can divide the declaration of a class or structure among several declarations by using the Partial keyword in Visual Basic or the partial keyword in Visual C#. You can use as many partial declarations as you want, in as many different source files as you want, or in one source file. However, all the declarations must be in the **same assembly** and the same namespace.'*

Comment: No, it can be done.  Designers are classes (though rather weird ones), so you can write them, put them in a DLL and import it for use on a control or component.  I currently tend to include them in the same class/file if they are custom, but if you have a generic UI Designer you can put them in a DLL.  That tends not to be too common because they often customized to work with a specific class (type).  This `http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/429800/Accessing-the-Controls-on-a-Form-at-Design-Time` will be in a DLL when I/we get done with it.

Comment: @Plutonix - So I have tried doing what you have suggested for the last couple of days, and while I am sure that you are correct, the process seems a little over my head.  I was wondering if you would be willing to start a conversation in the chat area to discuss this more in detail. I would start the conversation myself, but I am 5 Rep points short of the 100 needed to start one.  I would REALLY appreciate it as I am fairly certain that this is the LAST thing I need to do before this whole project is done.

Comment: @ProtoNoob I can do that...first, see if the post below helps though.  Also, you get 2 rep points for editting posts until you get to 1000 or 2000 or something, so you could easily get to 100 by simply formatting code blocks posted by novice users (add whitespace to get past the minimum chars requirement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause of Problem Verified**

First, I would like to point out that indeed, the issue of losing track of the namespace in the referenced dll was because of the presence of custom UI editor/designers in that dll.

**The Fix**

The **general process** of separating Custom Editors/Designers from a 'primary' class library is this:

**1.)** Find all custom editors/designers in the project.  If you are only somewhat familiar with the project, a good way to do that is to Find *(Ctrl + F)* 'UITypeEditor' in the entire solution.  If you are the one who designed it, then you should have no problem.

**2.)** Delete or comment out the entire custom editors/designers class(es).  I prefer commenting out for easy documentation (just in case you need to go back).

**3.)** Create new project in solution.  If you cannot see the solution (i.e. you can only see the project) go to tools-->options-->Projects and Solutions.  There you will see a check box that says 'Always show solution'.  After revealing the solution, right click and select add-->New Project...   Can be named whatever, that will have little to no effect on the code.

**4.)** Within the new project rename Class1 to whatever is convenient.  Transfer all 'using' statements at the top of the files that originally held the custom editor/designer classes.  **EDIT: Add using statements for any namespaces that would allow you to access the types needed from the primary project.** Declare the appropriate namespace for each class.  Copy and paste custom classes into correct namespaces (You can, if you want, place ALL of your custom editor/designers in this one file).  Change any classes that are declared as 'internal' to 'public' (internal is only the scope of the assembly).

**5.)** If the new project requires any references, add those now.  If your custom editor is editing custom types, you will likely need a reference to the project that defines those types.  If those types are defined in your 'primary' assembly this can get a bit tricky as it could cause a circular reference issue.  One way to get around this, and probably the right way, is to remove the declaration of those types from your primary assembly and create a new project/assembly just for their declaration.  If they are, for some reason, inseparable from your primary assembly, set aside a successful build (dll) previously made of you primary assembly and reference that.  This reduces future sustainability of code as those types may chance, but gets the job done now if that is what you want.

**6.)** After debugging the custom editor/designer project, build it and add that project's build (dll) as reference in the primary project/assembly.

**7.)** Debug *internally*, create a new project in solution and add **BOTH** dlls (Primary and Custom Editor) to the references. Verify controls/properties behave as they are supposed to in both design time AND run time.

**8.)**  Finally, debug *externally*.  Create new solution, reference both dlls, verify functionality.  It may seem overkill to debug in both the native solution and externally, but I found many differences in behavior between the environments.  Be thorough.

**Important Note:**  I spent a **LONG** time figuring that both dlls needed to be added.  You see, when adding just the primary dll to the test project, it would act as though BOTH were added.  I though this was reasonable (& quite dandy) as the primary assembly references the other assembly.  However, close and open Visual Studio and it does not work.  Long story short add BOTH dlls.

**TreeViewAdv Specifics**

**1.)** There were two Custom UIEditors.  The first is in NodeControlsCollection.cs called NodeControlCollectionEditor, which inherits the standard .NET CollectionEditor.  The only functionality added was the explicit assigning of what kind of controls the editor is allowed to work with.  It seems this was largely done as a workaround to allow ALL NodeControl types to be added to the collection (this required the passing of type NodeControl), but get around the fact that passing the NodeControl type causes an error because you cannot instantiate an abstract type.  The second is StringCollectionEditor in StringCollectionEditor.cs. This also inherets the standard .NET CollectionEditor and adds a little functionality (Not sure of the purpose).

**2 - 4.)** Same as the general process.

**5.)**  I currently had to use the latter method (setting aside a dll of Aga.Controls for my custom UIEditor to reference).  Later I hope to separate some of the object declarations from the primary assembly to make the solution more reliable.

**6 - 8.)**  The original bug (losing the aga namespace) did not occur when running the testing application inside the same solution (even if different project).  Additionally, some fixes that worked externally did not run correctly internally and vise-versa.  Thus, my advice for testing in both environments.

**Final Request**
While both the general and specifics of my question is answered here, Plutonix's help was vital in my coming to the solution.  While I am marking this as the answer.  I would like if people also upvote Plutonix's answer given the effort that he has put forth in helping me find the answer (in addition to the fact that his answer is also correct if less specific).

**EDIT:** The process outlined above worked when I was modifying the original TVA C# code.  I was even able to reference and successfully use the resulting DLLs in a VB.net project. When I tried to apply the same process to the TVA code line that I had converted into VB.net, it resulted in the same problem that I started with.  Everything works until I go to run the application and then it loses sight of the aga namespace.

**EDIT SOLUTION:**  Go to properties (of project losing reference)--> Compile tab --> Advanced Compile Options button.  Under target framework, change to ".NET Framework 4" if not so already.  If that value is already selected, you are likely looking at a different cause.

Comment: P.S.:  Clean and Rebuild your inter-referencing projects often.  This also caused me some difficulty.
.
P.P.S.:  I will see about getting this codeline available to the public as it solves the "TreeViewAdv doesn't work with 2010" thing.  I am also almost done with the VB conversion.  I will get that out when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit more info addressing the *general* issue of a Designer in a different assembly.  There are some caveats: first I (we?) are not sure that the core problem as to do with a *UI* Designer.  Given the project appears to be a custom TreeView, it seems likely to be the case, but the term 'Designer' could be used in a more generic fashion for this control.  A second caveat is that all I have to go on is the description above and havent seen the code for the control.

That said, I am just finishing a drop in UnDo Manager component (ie it inherits from Component and sits in the form tray).  Part of what it needed was a way for the dev to select controls on the form to be subject to UnDo.  The layout/construction is this:

```
Imports Plutonix.UIDesigners

Namespace Plutonix.UnDoMgr

Public Class UndoManager
    Inherits Component      
    Implements ISupportInitialize      

    Private _TgtControls As New Collection(Of Control)

    <EditorAttribute(GetType(UnDoControlCollectionUIEditor), _
          GetType(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))> _
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)> _
    Public Property UnDoTargets() As Collection(Of Control)
        Get
            Return _TgtControls
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Collection(Of Control))
            If value IsNot Nothing Then
                _TgtControls = value
            Else
                _TgtControls.Clear()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    '...
```

The `<EditorAttribute...` decoration specifies that this component uses a special designer called `UnDoControlCollectionUIEditor`.  If the project you are converting does not have this on one or more properties, the issue may not be related to *UI* designers.

Later, there is the UI editor for the COntrols collection editor.  This is a separate class though it is in the same file:

```
  <System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSetAttribute( _
        System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")> _
Public Class UnDoControlCollectionUIEditor
    Inherits ControlCollectionUIEditor

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.bExcludeForm = True
        MyBase.bExcludeSelf = True

       ' create a list of supported control TYPES
        typeList.Add(GetType(TextBox))
        '... 9 more lines adding control types to List(of System.Type)
    End Sub
 End Class
```

Nearly all the code resides in the base class `ControlCollectionUIEditor` which is in a different assembly (a DLL).  My component though is actually using one defined locally, so as a test, I changed the editor to use to `ControlCollectionUIEditor` which is the base class in my designer DLL.  Labels, panels, GroupBoxes etc dont have/need UnDo capability so my Designer exempts them from showing in the Designer - when I use the base class, they all show up in the designer list as expected.

ALL the standard UI Editors (String Collection Editor and the like) are in NET assemblies, so are defined in one assembly and used in another (yours/ours/the devs).  A few years ago, I decided to put several different UIDesigners I had written into a UIDesigner.DLL (ie their own assembly) and they worked fine.

Beyond that, I am confused on some specifics.  It sounds like you are trying to use this 2008 assembly (a DLL?) in your conversion.  Is that where the designer is?  If so, it is already in another assembly from your VS 2010 project, so why is there an issue?  Can the whole thing be avoided by also converting whatever is in this 2008 assembly (still not clear on what is in it).

HTH

EDIT

I had a quick look at the source, and it is using at least 1 UIDesigner.  `TreeViewAdv.Properties.cs` defines `NodeControlCollectionEditor` as a custom controls collection editor for the `NodeControls` property. The Editor is in `NodeControlsCollection.cs`.  Coincidentally, it is doing EXACTLY what my UnDoManager does: define what control types are valid for a CollectionEditor.  Your thing then calls the standard NET CollectionEditor, mine calls the CodeProject DialogForm version.  There is also a `StringCollectionEditor.cs` file but I cant tell if that is a UI Designer or something for the user at runtime.

Since you have the code for these, you should be able to mimic something like what I did above. I would also verify that VS 2010 does indeed have the quirk mentioned.  But I am also confused what is in the 2008 assembly.  Is there some piece that you dont have the source for?  You might also try adding the security attribute to any UI Designers in the project since the CS version does not have them and the msg quoted indicates something about 'protection level'.  It seems unlikely to help, but since you are dealing with a quirk, who knows...?

Also, that is a pretty ambitious conversion project!

Comment: Thank you, this will give me a bit more to work on.  One thing that just cleared up for me is what YOU were referring to as UI Designer... The window that pops up when you press the ellipsis on a control property.  I'm sorry, but there are SO MANY things called designers in NET that doing a search and getting exactly what you want is just impossible. They MS needs to diversify their vocabulary.

Comment: actually the official MS term for them is `UIEditor` it is US that tend to call them designers because it is something we write to use in the VS Designer at Design time.  Um...feel free to upvote this - I think that gets you points too, so you can start a chat if you need to.

Comment: I have made some headway, but I have run into some additional issues.  I have started a conversation 'TreeViewAdv Conversation'.  Hope to see you there.